# Converse to the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

By the Jordan curve theorem, if $C \subset S^2$ is (the image of) a simple closed curve, then $S^2 \setminus C$ has precisely two connected components. This statement admits the following "converse".

> **Converse of Jordan curve theorem:** Suppose $M$ is a closed, connected surface such that, if $C \subset M$ is a simple closed curve, then  $M \setminus C$ has precisely two connected components. Then, $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

This statement is a corollary of the [classification of surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Classification_of_closed_surfaces).

- Multiple tori have handles, and it's easy to see that deleting a loop which "grasps" a handle leaves a connected complement.
- Any non orientable surface contains a Mobius band, and the Mobius band minus its "equator" is connected.

Thus, any closed, connected surface $M$, besides $S^2$, admits a simple closed curve $C \subset M$ such that $M \setminus C$ is connected.

My question is whether this also works in higher dimensions. Does the following "converse" to the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem hold?

> **Converse of Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem:** Suppose $M$ is a compact, connected $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. Suppose that, for every embedded copy $C \subset M$ of $S^{n-1}$, it occurs that $M \setminus C$ has precisely two connected components. Does it then follow that $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already false in dimension 3: Take M to be any "homology 3-sphere", not homeomorphic to the 3-sphere. For instance, Poincare homology sphere will do the job.

That is true is that the topological Poincaré conjecture holds in all dimensions.

Comment: So... the idea is to somehow deduce that $H_0(M \setminus C) \cong \mathbb{Z}  \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MikeF: Yes, "somehow" refers to the Alexander-Lefschetz-Poincare duality: $\tilde{H}_{0}(M-C)\cong H^{n-1}(C)\cong Z$, where "tilde" is the reduced homology.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know a good reference for that result?

Comment: @MikeF: You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality. It should be in Hatcher, but I do not know for sure. Check also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41978/intuition-behind-alexander-duality.